# Find text in variable

Tags: jquery, variables

I have a variable that contains a bunch of stuff like this:

```
\"message\":\"BUY ONE, GET ONE 30% OFF!\",\"messages\":[],\"status\":\"success\",\"success\":true,\"type\":null,\"url\":\"/content/modal/blah\"}],\"proposition65\":null,\
```

How do I look inside this variable and make a new variable that equals `/content/modal/blah`

This will change all the time so something that looks for

```
\"success\":true,\"type\":null,\"url\":\" then slices off and grabs whats next and then slices off \"}],\"proposition65\":null,\
```

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/06/jquery-string-functions.html

Comment: regex or preferably $.parseJSON then var->url

Comment: In particular, have a look at `substring` and `indexof`. You can combine these to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mentioned in the comments, the best way to deal with this would be to use

`var results = JSON.parse(yourString)`
and then get the url
`results.url` or `results[url]`

however, if you cannot have your data in JSON format, you could also use regex

```
var str = '\"message\":\"BUY ONE, GET ONE 30% OFF!\",\"messages\":[],\"status\":\"success\",\"success\":true,\"type\":null,\"url\":\"/content/modal/blah\"}],\"proposition65\":null,'

var regex = str.match(/url\":\"(.*(?=\"}))/); 
 // regex will return an array, the url will be in the groupe 1 as groupe 0 is just the string url\":\"
 console.log(regex[1])
```

I am not an expert on regex but here is how the one I crafted works

```
url\":\"      // this gets the string url\":\"
(.*(?=\"}))   // here we capture a group with () then match any characters with .* which are followed by \"}) with (?=\"})
```

this will return an array with two matching groups, one containing `url\":\"` and one containing the string you want, so you can access that data via `array[1]`

you can see the working code here 
https://jsfiddle.net/3s61ory2/7/

and play with the regex here :
[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/gtPhR1EpabAJF-qp)